# How to identify the surrounding closed polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

[image]

These polygons are one residential street, but here how to people access the inner houses, so rectify this problem to identify surrounding closed polygon.

Comment: Is it really housed completely enclosed and not a data error: an interior court wrongly digitized? I met such cases in OpenStreetMap data, so before applying the solutions you got below make sure the data really respresent what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

1. Create a scratch layer and draw a large polygon covering your layer, I call it Extent
2. Difference this layer and your layer, creating a large polygon with a hole where your polygons are:

[image]

3. Extract or Select by expression, the polygons from your layer that are disjoint from the difference output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This expression should do it:

```
length(
 intersection(
  buffer(
   collect_geometries(
    overlay_intersects(@layer,$geometry)
   )
  ,100),
 boundary($geometry))
)
=
length(
 boundary($geometry)
)
```

You can e.g. use it in select by expression. The idea is to measure the length of the boundary of a polygon and compare it with the length of the intersection. You can set a tolerance (here 100).

If you need even more tolerance because the neighboring polygons actually do not touch, you can use overlay_nearest() instead of intersects, as this:

```
length(
 intersection(
  buffer(
   collect_geometries(
    overlay_nearest(@layer,$geometry,limit:=-1,max_distance:=100)
   )
  ,100),
 boundary($geometry))
)
=
length(
 boundary($geometry)
)
```